# JavaScript Google Maps API - Center on User's Location not loading map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I've posted before but I wanted to update the question, I tried to delete the other question but I had to flag it do that so I left it alone.
**I have a key for the Google Map API, but the map will not appear or load.**
Here is my code:

**Index.html**

```
<script src = "loc.js"></script>
<input type ="button" value="Get Location" onclick="getLocation();">
<div id="spot"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDEiqN2L1odkK645Il8bBVCDqatth6aZyU&callback=getLocation"></script>
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
```

**loc.js**

```
function getLocation() {
    var userSpot = document.getElementById("spot");
    var map = document.getElementById("map");
    //Using navigator, retrieves the users current location (works better with mobile phones)
    if (navigator.geolocation) { //If the user says no (this prompts the user if they want their location known)
                                //then it'll go ahead and retrieve their location, if not prompts error message.
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation);

        var currPosLat = position.coords.latitude; 
        var currPosLng = position.coords.longitude;

        var mapOptions = { 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(currPosLat, currPosLng),
        zoom:12, 
        }; 

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    } else { 
        userSpot.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser type.";
    }
}

function showLocation(position) {
    var userSpot = document.getElementById("spot");
    //Retrieves latitude and longitude using this second function called in the first
    userSpot.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Comment: To highlight, the main issue is with the div id = map which is where the map should be, and the getLocation method in the loc.js. That's where my problem is originating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, I tested it locally and over HTTPS, the map will load properly. There were couple issues with your code.

You need to load Google Maps API using `async` attribute:

> The async attribute lets the browser render the rest of your website
>   while the Maps JavaScript API loads. When the API is ready, it will
>   call the function specified using the callback parameter.

Refer to Google's documentation here: [Loading the Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)

Also, make sure the live version is going through secure origin, otherwise you will get these two warning:

> **[Deprecation]** getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work
>   on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider
>   switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See
>   https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for more details.
>
> **ERROR(1):** Only secure origins are allowed (see:
>   https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features).

Map initialization needs to be within `showLocation()` function, position coordinates are currently not passed back to `getLocation()`, moving your initialization into `showLocation()` will render the map.

**Keep in mind that if your geolocation is not switched on jsFiddle will display a console warning:**

> ERROR(1): User denied Geolocation

Test it locally or on your server to view the working version.

**Revised version with marker based on browser geolocation:**

```js
function getLocation() {
 var userSpot = document.getElementById("spot");
 var map = document.getElementById("map");
 //Using navigator, retrieves the users current location (works better with mobile phones)
    if (navigator.geolocation) { //If the user says no (this prompts the user if they want their location known)
        //then it'll go ahead and retrieve their location, if not prompts error message.
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, error);
        
    } else { 
        userSpot.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser type.";
    }
}

function showLocation(position) {
 var userSpot = document.getElementById("spot");
 //Retrieves latitude and longitude using this second function called in the first
    userSpot.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    
    var currPosLat = position.coords.latitude; 
    var currPosLng = position.coords.longitude;
    var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(currPosLat, currPosLng);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    
    var mapOptions = { 
      center: centerPosition,
      zoom:12
    }; 

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    bounds.extend(centerPosition);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: centerPosition,
        map: map,
        //icon: 'map.png',
        title: 'Some Random Location'
    });
    
};

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
};
```

```html
<script src = "loc.js"></script>
<input type ="button" value="Get Location" onclick="getLocation();">
<div id="spot"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDEiqN2L1odkK645Il8bBVCDqatth6aZyU&callback=getLocation"></script>
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this completely made it work. I see how that works as well, not sure what async is but it did the trick as well as the rest of the code. I remember seeing in my textbook the bounds and marker variables, but didn't think to include it. Also, a side question, what are those "$" symbols used in the function error? Such as: ('ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}'); It almost seems like another language, having curly brackets within parentheses and a colon in the middle.

Comment: Great. Not a different language at all, still javascript. `err.code` return the error code (if there is one) and `err.message` returns the message related to the error code.